# How to filter an array of object in Mui DataGrid?

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

I recently changed my tables to [Mui-datagrid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid) on Material UI 5, and I have a special use case with an array of objects. I want to enable the phone number filter in this column, but the number is provided as an object list.

```
 phone: [
  { type: "home", number: "795-946-1806" },
  { type: "mobile", number: "850-781-8104" }
]
```

I was expecting a `'customFilterAndSearch'` or an option to customise how to search in this specific field.

```
   customFilterAndSearch: (term, rowData) =>
    !!rowData?.suppressedOptions.find(({ description }) =>
      description?.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
    ),
```

I have made some tries with the `filterOperators`, but no success yet. I have made a full example here https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-data-grid-vs05fr?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from the DataGrid documentation I don't see any way to change the filter function for a specific function.

Likely the best workaround for your use case will be converting this to a string be converting the data to a string before you pass it to the datagrid. Though you will lose the styling that you currently do by making the phone type **bold**.

**On second though your best best would probably be to split the phone column into two columns which would probably be the cleanest way of solving your problem**

Add helper function.

You could potentially add a helper function to just map all the phone lists to something like `mobilePhone` or `homePhone`

```
const mapPhoneObject = (rows) => {
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        row.phone.forEach((phone) => {
          row[`${phone.type}Phone`] = phone.number;
        });
      });
      return rows
    };
```

I've added a fork of your snippet with my function, it is I think the most viable solution for your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-data-grid-forked-ppii8y

Comment: Both workarounds work! What I have made for now is exactly what you suggested in the first one. I have to use the valueGetter to join my values in a string divided by a comma, and in the renderCell I have changed the logic using split to get an array with the results. I do not think that is the best solution, but it is the one it works well for me.

Comment: In my case, this is the best solution, because my original situation has a different renderCell layout + data. I am adding here the solution as well, just if someone else is looking how to use valueGetter: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-data-grid-forked-y9m4rf?file=/demo.js